# PDAL info with docker yields no output?

Tags: installation, lidar, metadata, las, pdal

I am using `pdal info` within a docker env for a specific .las file (~2 GB).

```
docker run -v /Users/user.name/workspaces/testData:/data pdal/pdal pdal info /data/sp.las --developer-debug
```

Unfortunately, I get no output and no errors, just nothing, but it works with smaller files.

Using `lasinfo` from LASTools works. Here is the output from `lasinfo`:

```
lasinfo (180520) report for 'sp.las' reporting all LAS header entries: file signature: 'LASF' file source ID: 1 global_encoding: 0 project ID GUID data 1-4: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 version major.minor: 1.2 system identifier: 'Agisoft PhotoScan' generating software: 'Agisoft PhotoScan' file creation day/year: 238/2016 header size: 227 offset to point data: 698 number var. length records: 3 point data format: 2 point data record length: 26 number of point records: 67003099 number of points by return: 67003099 0 0 0 0 scale factor x y z: 0.0001 0.0001 0.0001 offset x y z: 455000 5706000 100 min x y z: 455426.5285 5706750.6877 106.5704 max x y z: 455544.0945 5706861.8590 122.6846 variable length header record 1 of 3: reserved 0 user ID 'LASF_Projection' record ID 34735 length after header 200 description '' GeoKeyDirectoryTag version 1.1.0 number of keys 24 key 1024 tiff_tag_location 0 count 1 value_offset 1 - GTModelTypeGeoKey: ModelTypeProjected key 1025 tiff_tag_location 0 count 1 value_offset 1 - GTRasterTypeGeoKey: RasterPixelIsArea key 2048 tiff_tag_location 0 count 1 value_offset 4258 - GeographicTypeGeoKey: look-up for 4258 not implemented key 2049 tiff_tag_location 34737 count 7 value_offset 0 - GeogCitationGeoKey: ETRS89 key 2050 tiff_tag_location 0 count 1 value_offset 6258 - GeogGeodeticDatumGeoKey: look-up for 6258 not implemented key 2051 tiff_tag_location 0 count 1 value_offset 8901 - GeogPrimeMeridianGeoKey: PM_Greenwich key 2054 tiff_tag_location 0 count 1 value_offset 9102 - GeogAngularUnitsGeoKey: Angular_Degree key 2055 tiff_tag_location 34736 count 1 value_offset 0 - GeogAngularUnitSizeGeoKey: 0.01745329252 key 2056 tiff_tag_location 0 count 1 value_offset 7019 - GeogEllipsoidGeoKey: Ellipse_GRS_1980 key 2057 tiff_tag_location 34736 count 1 value_offset 1 - GeogSemiMajorAxisGeoKey: 6378137 key 2059 tiff_tag_location 34736 count 1 value_offset 2 - GeogInvFlatteningGeoKey: 298.2572221 key 2061 tiff_tag_location 34736 count 1 value_offset 3 - GeogPrimeMeridianLongGeoKey: 0 key 3072 tiff_tag_location 0 count 1 value_offset 25833 - ProjectedCSTypeGeoKey: ETRS89 / UTM 33N key 3073 tiff_tag_location 34737 count 22 value_offset 7 - PCSCitationGeoKey: ETRS89 / UTM zone 33N key 3074 tiff_tag_location 0 count 1 value_offset 16033 - ProjectionGeoKey: Proj_UTM_zone_33N key 3075 tiff_tag_location 0 count 1 value_offset 1 - ProjCoordTransGeoKey: CT_TransverseMercator key 3076 tiff_tag_location 0 count 1 value_offset 9001 - ProjLinearUnitsGeoKey: Linear_Meter key 3077 tiff_tag_location 34736 count 1 value_offset 4 - ProjLinearUnitSizeGeoKey: 1 key 3080 tiff_tag_location 34736 count 1 value_offset 5 - ProjNatOriginLongGeoKey: 15 key 3081 tiff_tag_location 34736 count 1 value_offset 6 - ProjNatOriginLatGeoKey: 0 key 3082 tiff_tag_location 34736 count 1 value_offset 7 - ProjFalseEastingGeoKey: 500000 key 3083 tiff_tag_location 34736 count 1 value_offset 8 - ProjFalseNorthingGeoKey: 0 key 3092 tiff_tag_location 34736 count 1 value_offset 9 - ProjScaleAtNatOriginGeoKey: 0.9996 key 4099 tiff_tag_location 0 count 1 value_offset 9001 - VerticalUnitsGeoKey: Linear_Meter variable length header record 2 of 3: reserved 0 user ID 'LASF_Projection' record ID 34736 length after header 80 description '' GeoDoubleParamsTag (number of doubles 10) 0.0174533 6.37814e+06 298.257 0 1 15 0 500000 0 0.9996 variable length header record 3 of 3: reserved 0 user ID 'LASF_Projection' record ID 34737 length after header 29 description '' GeoAsciiParamsTag (number of characters 29) ETRS89|ETRS89 / UTM zone 33N| reporting minimum and maximum for all LAS point record entries ... X 4265285 5440945 Y 7506877 8618590 Z 65704 226846 intensity 0 65535 return_number 1 1 number_of_returns 1 1 edge_of_flight_line 0 0 scan_direction_flag 1 1 classification 0 0 scan_angle_rank 0 0 user_data 0 0 point_source_ID 1 1 Color R 0 65535 G 0 65535 B 0 65535 number of first returns: 67003099 number of intermediate returns: 0 number of last returns: 67003099 number of single returns: 67003099 overview over number of returns of given pulse: 67003099 0 0 0 0 0 0 histogram of classification of points: 67003099 never classified (0)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: If you [solved](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/299483/pdal-info-with-docker-yields-no-output#comment496881_306825) your question, then accept the answer you got, or add your own answer if it was a different approach which solved it. This way future users might benefit from your question as well. Also, I suggest replacing the [las] tag for one of the operating system you are working with (ubuntu?).Tks.

Answer (score 1):

You might have more success with Conda. PDAL is now available on Conda Forge on OSX, Win64, and Linux. Find out more on the [PDAL download page](https://pdal.io/download.html#conda).

Comment: Everything works as expected with pdal/ubuntu:master branch. Thanks!